# App Quality Insights in Android Studio fails with SSL error on corporate networks

Tags: firebase, android-studio, crashlytics

When i try to use Android studio behind a corporate firewall with self signed CA, it does not work. I just get an error indicating SSL certificate failed validation. It maybe due to certificates and i did add Root CAs to "Server Certificates" in IntelliJ still it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Updated RootCAs under Android studio Settings --> Server certificates.